# Best way to get documents in specific timeframe MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, isodate

I am creating a script that would run after every x minutes and needs to gather data from MongoDB by timestamps.

For example, how would I match the documents with aggregation that have a timestamp in the following timeframe:

```
start_time = current_time - 60 min
end_time = start_time + 30 min
```

And I would need to get all the documents that stay within that time frame.
The MongoDB objects have ISODate timestamps on them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create date objects in mongo shell like so:

```
db.getCollection('order').aggregate([
{
$match : { 
    start_time : {$gte :  new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60)},
    end_time : {$lte :  new Date(ISODate().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 30)}
    }
}
...
])
```

You can use this in aggregate but also in normal find queries.

Note I wrote this without testing, so it might have syntax errors..

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

db.collection.find({"createdAt": { $gt: new Date('2017-04-25')},"updatedAt":{$lt:new Date('2017-06-25')}})

updatedAt and createdAt are the feilds I have taken at the time of designing the schema by timestamp. You could give feilds according to you design.

the find query would be little better than aggregate in this case as no complex functions have to be performed